# z-index issue with fixed and relative div's in a container

Tags: html, css, css-float, z-index

I am facing an issue with z-index my layout draft form is here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunvavara/6hRdF/4/)

I am trying to achieve the following

1. The `#topBar` , `#Navigations` , `#infobar` needs to be fixed always.(achieved)
2. Z-index of the `#mainMenu` . Needs to be between `#contentBorder` and `#content`(has a shadow).
3. Z-index of the `#categorys`. Needs to be top of the `#contentBordera` and `#content`.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, where is the `#infobar`? Should it be that duplicated `#topBar` at the bottom of fiddle? :-) You can try to zeroize padding and margin and try to add higher `z-index` to #topBar than to #contentBorder: http://jsfiddle.net/6hRdF/7/ http://jsfiddle.net/6hRdF/7/show (Hope it helps a little.)

Comment: Thanks Stano. The margin is not what I am actually trying to fix I have given that topbar for a layout understanding.                       Themain issues I have been trying to fix is the z-index issues 2nd and 3rd points.

Comment: This seems to be a Chrome bug, other browsers draws divs right: http://jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/2/show

Answer (score 1):

Seen on [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> Definition and Usage
>
> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is give to the #sideBar a higher index than to the #contentBorder div, then all sub elements of #sideBar can overlap those within the #contentBorder:

```css
#topBar {
    z-index:2000;
}
#sideBar {
    z-index: 1900;
}
#mainMenu {
    z-index:1500;
}
#categorys {
    z-index:1800;
}
#contentBorder {
    z-index:1400;
}
#content {
    z-index:1600;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hRdF/13/

Comment: Hi stano when I increased the size of that #mainMenu to 165px it is not under the #content. means the shadow is not top of the #mainMenu. Can you please try increasing the length of #mainMenu to 165px

Comment: Yeah, it's because the `#sidebar` is above the `#contentBorder`, so the `#mainMenu`'s width shouldn't be increased, else it will overlay the contentBorder. Why do you want to increase it?

Comment: i need that #content's shadow above the #mainMenu.  please check http://jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/ . Now i only need that #categorys on top of the #content. Please check

Comment: Then probably you can try to move the `#mainMenu` div outside from the `#sidebar`, http://jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/1/ ?

Comment: Hi stano . Sorry I am unable to see the changes in your links. and I am loading all those sidebar elements dynamically.

Comment: Hi no other way to bring the #category  over the #content . Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/

Comment: Oh, my apologizes. **I tested [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/1/show/) only in Firefox and there the divs are stacked as needed.** Now tested also in Chrome, and **you're right, in Chrome are the categories hidden below the content.** I am sorry dunno why it doesn't work in Chrome. And I hope that somebody can answer your question better, why z-index behaves differently in Chrome than in Firefox.

Comment: Stano thanks a lot for your helps. The main thing is I am losing all sidebar elements like #mainMenu, #categorys dynamicaly into that #sideBar so I can't alter the stacking order of divs. In the following version i am able to z-index #mainmenu under #contents, #categorys is pulling me backward for a success finishing.  please check jsfiddle.net/BqFEN/